# Calling a custom method on the Array prototype in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, prototype

I'm trying to add a custom method on the prototype of the Array object:

```js
Array.prototype.demo = function(){
    this.forEach(i=>console.log(i))
}
```

But, I'm receiving the error below when I'm calling the method like this:

```js
[1,2,3].demo()

// Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'demo' of undefined
```

However, it runs successfully when I change it to:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
arr.demo()

// Output: 1, 2, 3
```

PS. This is in nodejs
To reproduce the error in the browser, copy/paste the full block at once and click enter.

UPDATE: It sounds like we need to add a semicolon to make it work:

```js
Array.prototype.demo = function(){
    this.forEach(i=>console.log(i))
};   <=== added semicolon here to work @jfriend00

[1,2,3].demo();
```

However, now this next code works WITHOUT semicolon!!

```js
String.prototype.demo = function(){
    this.split('').forEach(c=>console.log(c))
}

'hello'.demo();
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error (chrome, node, FF)

Comment: The error is in nodejs, but If you copy/paste the full block of code in the browser you will see the error.

Comment: The error is most definitely not in Node. If I copy-paste your code, it runs perfectly fine. The same goes for any browser.

Comment: My glass ball is telling me you are missing a semicolon, and ASI will not trigger. Therefore the "array" is seen as bracket property access. Add a semicolon at the end of your prototype assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908243/cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Fix - Add Semi-colon**

Add a semi-colon at the end of your function definition:

```js
Array.prototype.demo = function(){
    this.forEach(i=>console.log(i))
};    // <======

[1,2,3].demo();
```

And, it will work.

**What's Happening?**

The problem is that the `[1,2,3]` is being combined with the previous function (whitespace between them collapsed).  In that circumstance, the `[1,2,3]` becomes just `[3]` and tries to read the `[3]` property from the function object.  If you put the semi-colon at the end of the function definition, then that signals the end of the function definition statement and the `[1,2,3]` can then be interpreted as a static array definition.

It's all about context.  In some circumstances in Javascript, `[x]` is a property access.  In other circumstances, it's a static array definition.  Without the semi-colon, it was getting interpreted as the property access instead of the array definition.

Remember that functions are objects in Javascript so they can have properties and can respond to `[x]` as a property access on them.

So, without the semi-colon at the end of the function you essentially have this:

```
Array.prototype.demo = function() {...}[3].demo();
```

Because the whitespace is collapsed between the end of your function and the `[1,2,3]`.  That means the JS interpreter is expecting the `[]` to be a property name so it evaluates the statement inside the `[]` and in that context `[1,2,3]` turns into `[3]` (the `1,2,3` is evaluated which takes the value of the last comma separated statement which is `3`).

**More Detailed Explanation**

Think of it like this:

```js
// defines function
let f = function() {};       

// attempts to read a property from that function object
let o = f [1,2,3];           // this is the same as let o = f[3]

// tries to call `.demo()` on the value read from that property
// which was undefined so this throws
o.demo();
```

**Functions Are Objects**

As a demonstration of how functions are objects, see this example that actually works!

```js
// defines function
let f = function() {};       
f[3] = {demo: function() { console.log("demo!!!");}}

// attempts to read a property from that function object
let o = f[1,2,3];           // this is the same as let o = f[3]

// tries to call `.demo()` on the value read from that property
// which was undefined so this throws
o.demo();
```

Here, we actually put a property on the `[3]` property of the function so when `f[1,2,3]` reads that property, it actually gets an object with a `.demo()` method on it so when we then call it, it all works.  I'm not suggesting one would ever code this way, but I am trying to illustrate how `f[1,2,3]` is just reading the `[3]` property from the function object.

**Good Reason Not to Leave out the Semi-colons**

These odd cases are a good reason not to leave out semi-colons, even though you usually (but not always) get away with it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after adding the semi-colon. This is weird!

Comment: @Umurİnan - I added a bunch more explanation so you can see why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that functions are objects, so if we don't add a semicolon, JavaScript will try to access a property on the function object, after it evaluates the comma operator like this:

```js
function() { ... }[1,2,3].demo();
function() { ... }[3].demo();
undefined.demo();
```