# Openlayers - lines and points cannot be deleted by double click

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am working on the delete option by double click in OpenLayers.
I use the following code:

```
 map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
  var selectCollection = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
  if(selectCollection.getLength() > 0){
   var answer = window.confirm("Do you want to delete?")
   if (answer) {
   vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectCollection.item(0));
    }
  }
 });
```

based on these examples:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126581/openlayers-3-capturing-various-click-events

[How to create a dialog with “yes” and “no” options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/how-to-create-a-dialog-with-yes-and-no-options)

everything would be perfect, but I cannot delete the linestrings and points at some point.

As you can see below, all the shapes which have the "filled surface" can be deleted easily after the selection.

[image]

I am getting the

**Vector.js:906

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')**

instead.

I don't know how to fix it frankly.
By reading this hint:

[Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908243/cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined)

I think, that I should use the `push` method, although I see no option for distinguishing my  `selectInteraction` between the separate geometry.

My full JSFiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/skwbdx0j/

Is there any option to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

Placing a certain variable inside the `getSource` didn't resolve this issue.

```
 map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
 var selectCollection = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
 if(selectCollection.getLength() > 0){
 var answer = window.confirm("Do you want to delete?")
  if (answer) {
  
  vectorLayer.getSource(lineInteraction).  // the same line
   removeFeature(selectCollection.item(0));           }
      }       
   });
```

Comment: You would get that error if you tried to remove the same feature twice.  Removing a feature from the source will not automatically remove it from the select collection.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ok, I got you. No! The error comes even from the first code example. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: After removing `item(0)` from the source remove it from the collection     `vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectCollection.item(0)); selectCollection.removeAt(0);`

Comment: The following one   'vectorLayer.getSource(lineInteraction).removeFeature(selectCollection.removeAt(0));'
still doesn't work. The error is exactly the same.