# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach)

Tags: node.js, testing, automation

[Unable to figure out why this error is showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgB87.jpg)

Comment: The error states .data is undefined. Make it not undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are trying to loop though the `data` object which is not a array. You can only use the `forEach()` function on arrays. In addition, the `data` object is undefined meaning that it does not exist.

Since I can not see all of your code, please check out this question [Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908243/cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined) on how to fix the undefined `data` object. If that still doesn't fix the problem, read up on the documentation for [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest).